# Stroke width on d3 v3 line chart

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I’m working with a responsive line chart in D3 v3 and I’m having issues making the stroke width of the axes. Right now they are super thick and I keep adding a `stroke-width` style to the axes and nothing is changing.

(Please see line 149 of the JSFiddle)
https://jsfiddle.net/t6vzegqp/7/

```
var xAxisEl = artboard.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
.attr("stroke-width", "3px");
```

How can I update the `stroke-width` of each axis?

Comment: wow, you are using d3 v3, i'd recommend using the latest version, this one is way outdated. The styling is not working because it's actually a path 6px wide. try to style the fill attr and stroke to check the differences

Comment: As @CarlosMoura pointed, you're using a very outdated version of D3 (5 y.o at least) and you need to rewrite your code with V6 (JS Fiddle does not have an option for V6, but you can specify it as en external resource: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.7.0/d3.min.js). I'm quite sure it will solve the problem with axis as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a useful [resource for d3 v3 axes](http://bl.ocks.org/emmasaunders/f92e3d68d0d910af7f8c8ff87f5b2468) - you can address your issue with some CSS:

```
path.domain {
  fill: none;
  stroke: slategray;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

You should get this:

[image]

I tend to agree with the commentators that it could be time to move on from this version of D3 - if your circumstances permit it, of course...

A v6 port of your fiddle doesn't have this stroke-width issue with the axis and they work out of the box:

```js
// DATA
var data = [{
    year: "2002",
    population: 191207000
  },
  {
    year: "2003",
    population: 192618000
  },
  {
    year: "2004",
    population: 175096000
  },
  {
    year: "2005",
    population: 172282000
  },
  {
    year: "2006",
    population: 177793000
  },
  {
    year: "2007",
    population: 181036000
  },
  {
    year: "2008",
    population: 176943000
  },
  {
    year: "2009",
    population: 184521000
  },
  {
    year: "2010",
    population: 173823000
  },
  {
    year: "2011",
    population: 171140000
  },
  {
    year: "2012",
    population: 172033000
  },
  {
    year: "2013",
    population: 180738000
  },
  {
    year: "2014",
    population: 179023000
  },
  {
    year: "2015",
    population: 177430000
  },
  {
    year: "2016",
    population: 190636623
  },
  {
    year: "2017",
    population: 199579997
  },
  {
    year: "2018",
    population: 201327425
  },
  {
    year: "2019",
    population: 207633646
  },
  {
    year: "2020",
    population: 218370375
  }
];

// Parse the date / time
var timeParse = d3.timeParse("%Y");
var formatValue = d3.format(".2s");

// force types
function type(dataArray) {
    dataArray.forEach(function(d) {
        d.year = timeParse(d.year);
        d.retention = +d.population;
    });
    return dataArray;
}
data = type(data);

// CHART CONFIG

// Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph
var margin = {top: 5, right: 0, bottom: 30, left: 65},
  width, // width gets defined below
  height = 250 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// Set the scales ranges
var xScale = d3.scaleTime();
var yScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

// Define the axes
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom().scale(xScale);
var yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
  .scale(yScale)
  .tickFormat(function(d) {
    return formatValue(d)
  });;

// create a line
var line = d3.line();

// Add the svg canvas
var svg = d3.select("#police-chart2")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

var artboard = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + 65 + "," + 5 + ")");

// set the domain range from the data
xScale.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
  return d.year;
}));
yScale.domain([
  d3.min(data, function(d) {
    return Math.floor(d.population - 5000000);
  }),
  d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return Math.floor(d.population + 5000000);
  })
]);

// draw the line created above
var path = artboard.append("path").data([data])
  .style('fill', 'none')
  .style('stroke', 'blue')
  .style('stroke-width', '3px');

// Add the X Axis
var xAxisEl = artboard.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")



// Add the Y Axis
var yAxisEl = artboard.append("g")
  .call(yAxis);

// styling the line bars
svg.append("text")
  .attr("class", "y-label")
  .attr("text-anchor", "end")
  .attr("y", 12)
  .attr("x", -20)
  .attr("yAxis", "1em")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .text("Department of Safety Budget ($M)");

// DRAWING
function drawChart() {

  window_width = parseInt(d3.select('body').style('width'), 10)
  // TODO: Calibrate this:
  // console.log(window_width);
  if (window_width < 500)
    margin_right = 0.2 * window_width;
  else {
    margin_right = 0.5 * window_width;
  }

  // reset the width
  width = parseInt(d3.select('body').style('width'), 10) - margin.left - margin_right;

  // set the svg dimensions
  svg.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin_right);

  // Set new range for xScale
  xScale.range([0, width]);

  // give the x axis the resized scale
  xAxis.scale(xScale);

  // draw the new xAxis
  xAxisEl.call(xAxis);

  // specify new properties for the line
  line.x(function(d) {
      return xScale(d.year);
    })
    .y(function(d) {
      return yScale(d.population);
    });

  // draw the path based on the line created above
  path.attr('d', line);
}

// call this once to draw the chart initially
drawChart();


// RESIZING
// redraw chart on resize
window.addEventListener('resize', drawChart);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div class="svg" id="police-chart2"></div>
```